# How to bind Postman key and value pair data to Pojo Class using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am passing below request to an api using postman.

```
{
  "user": {
    "phone":"1111111111",
    "email": "sample@gmail.com"
  },
  "eIdentifier": {
    "cIdentifier": [
      {
        "name": "Fname",
        "value": "Test"
      },
        {
        "name": "Lname",
        "value": "Test"
      },
       {
        "name": "Product",
        "value": "Pouch"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In local env, I tried passing request from postman to middleware, all the data are binding properly and getting saved in 3rd party application. But in front end, user will have UI, to select product, email, first name, last name and phone number. When user clicks Login button, all those parameters will be passed to a middleware, and from middleware data should bind accordingly as per above syntax and send it to a third-party application to store the information.

How can I bind the data from front end to middleware for this key and value cIdentifier arraylist?

Comment: Does the middleware provide an API?

Comment: Yes.  This is used for create api  -  /create

Comment: To pass your json data, you have use this API that is available. But you will have a constrains related to the contract provided by this API. You will have to readapt the content of your json to match the API contract.

Comment: I used the same structure being used for front-end UI, which solves my issue.